# WireGuard VM or Container to act as gateway

Tags: vpn, gateway, wireguard, proxmox

I have a home server running Proxmox with 9 VM's and CT's. I would love to be able to route specific VM/CT traffic through a VPN gateway. I know that this can be done with OpenVPN, but it's quite limiting in terms speed (I have 1Gig UP/DOWN connection). So I've been trying to find a tutorial or guide of how set up a WireGuard VPN server gateway.

What have I figured out:

- I would need to have subscription with VPN provider which provides WireGuard conf files, I'm thinking about Mullvad.
- I will install a WireGuard server using this guide: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-20-04-set-up-wireguard-vpn-server/

and them I'm kinda lost. Mainly on how to make the server route traffic.

Example scenario:

Container running geo-blocked service → Change the default gateway of this container to point to Wireguard Server -> Voilà no geo-block.

Comment: Start by reading the [official documentation](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/), then come back when you have problems implementing that.

Comment: @mashuptwice I tried following the documentation. Tried doing by changing default gateway and tried using the "The New Namespace Solution". The only thing I've achieved is breaking network connectivity. Traffic forwarding works if I kill the wg0 interface, but the moment I enable it, forwarding stops working. VPN itself works fine.

Here is my conf, maybe I missed something?
https://pastebin.com/NG8ED0GE

Comment: Impossible to say, as you didn't include any steps you've taken. Also why use the more complicated approach?

Comment: This is the configuration I tried: https://pastebin.com/khC1egir

What would be the easiest way to do this then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working. This is for anybody who wants to achieve the same as me.

1. Install Ubuntu, install Wireguard server.
2. Create a wg0.conf using your VPN provider's configuration. In my case, I had to use this python script https://github.com/hsand/pia-wg to extract PIA WireGuard configuration. My wg0 configuration looks something like this:

[image]

3. Test VPN connectivity, if everything works, you can continue.
4. Next, enable IP forwarding, I used this post:  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux. At this point, I tested that forwarding works, by setting my Wireguard VPN as the default gateway for my w11 test VM (Your VPN tunnel needs to be disabled for now, as the forwarding with that isn't configured yet). Tracert to google.com shows that Wireguard VM is one of the hops, so everything works.
5. Next, I changed my virtual machine NIC’s name servers to use PIA DNS servers (Can be found on their website or copied from wg0 configuration https://helpdesk.privateinternetaccess.com/kb/articles/using-pia-dns-in-custom-configurations). I’ll explain later why I did this. NIC configuration:

[image]

6. Next comes the main part which makes this all work, IPTABLES configuration. I got an already made script from Craft Computing YouTube channel (https://youtu.be/xFficDCEv3c), modified some settings to fit my use case. See the sections which begin with "CHANGED", those are the settings I changed.
   https://pastebin.com/H2yrqXMF

   I saved iptables.sh in my /etc/wireguard/ folder.
7. Next, enable your WireGuard tunnel and run the Iptables script using `sudo bash iptables.sh` . (This broke my SSH, but I didn’t mind as I control the server from Proxmox console.)

**Why use PIA DNS servers?**

When testing this configuration for DNS leaks, I noticed that my machine still used my IPS’s DNS server, effectively leaking my public IP. This is why in step 5 I changed the DNS configuration of the VPN VM and also the DNS settings of the machine which is routing its traffic though VPN.

**How I use this:**

On a machine I want the traffic to be routed through WireGuard VPN, I set the default gateway to the address of my WireGuard VM and DNS servers to PIA’s DNS servers.

I don’t know if this is the best way to do this, but this works for me.

**About the IPtables**

They are set up in a way if the VPN tunnel goes down, no traffic will be redirected. Essentially acting as "Kill Switch".

Comment: I suppose not many people are doing it this way, or maybe those that are already know how to craft the perfect iptables scripts? Anyway, thank you for providing an answer to your own question once you figured it all out. It turned out to be just what I was looking for and I found the 3 (or maybe 10) places I was headed in the wrong direction.